# I want to ignore whitespaces with regular expression in jmeter

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I want to ignore the whitespace in regex for correlation in jmeter.

This is my expression given below and i need to correlate the values inside single quotes.
Here there is a space and 3 tab after the variable "*var_SampleData*"

```
var __SampleData = [['CONSN_4578', '787', '01/01/2010', 'Active']];
```

I tried using regular expressions like:

1. `var __SampleData\s+ = [['(.+?)', '(.+?)', '01/01/2010', 'Active']];`
2. `var __SampleData\s* = [['(.+?)', '(.+?)', '01/01/2010', 'Active']];`
3. `var __SampleData = [['(.+?)', '(.+?)', '01/01/2010', 'Active']];`

Thanks
Bichu

Answer (score 1):

```
var __SampleData\s*= \[\['(.+?)', '(.+?)', '01\/01\/2010', 'Active'\]\];
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aM3uV1/2)